# Загрузка файла в обход https

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, https

Друзья, проблема такая. Есть скрипт, который загружает на мой сервер файлы. (СРАЗУ ГОВОРЮ, ЛЕЗТЬ В СКРИПТ НЕЛЬЗЯ, так как это прошивка самого контроллера установленного в оборудовании). Данный скрипт грузит файлы на сервер. Когда сервер был просто http - файлы принимались. В данный момент я установил ssl сертификат, и путем .htaccess сделал редирект на https. Теперь файлы перестали прилетать.

Вопрос. Можно ли как то расшифровать папку на сайте, где находится мой парсер, который обрабатывает загрузку файла, или что можно сделать что бы я наконец получал файлы?

Вот что прописано в htaccess в данный момент

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаешь так:

1. Элемент списка
2. Выключяшь https
3. Включаешь веб панель разработчика в chrome/ff
4. Загружаешь файл и запоминаешь url загрузки
5. Добавляешь исключение в .htaccess

Comment: не совсем понял про урл загрузки? в документации скрипта есть четкий регламент по какому урл он грузит, это http://domain.com/index.php?r=Terminals/Upload&id=09323

Comment: у тебя должно быть что-то типа http://stackoverflow.com/a/27595347/5996783  или http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065065/redirecting-from-https-to-http-with-the-exception-of-some-uris

Comment: Спасибо за примеры. думаю они подойдут что бы решить мою проблему и создать исключения!